# What can I purchase with in game gold?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

In Heroes of the Storm I know that I can purchase heroes with in-game gold. Is there anything else I can purchase with that gold: skins, mounts, etc.?

Comment: AFAIK there are some skins and mounts that can **only** be bought with gold. But I'm not sure which ones. I only know about the Elite skins.

Comment: After getting a Hero to level 10, you can spend 10K gold on their Elite skin. You can also purchase the Piggy Bank mount for 10K gold.

Comment: @ChaseC The Piggy Bank I believe is still 20K. However, that does cover everything (Heroes, Master Skin, Piggy Bank).

Comment: You are correct...20K for Piggy Bank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, in game gold can be used to purchase two things:

- Master Skins, which can be bought for 10,000 Gold when you have a Hero at Level 10 which is explained in the [Progression System and Reward Changes blog post](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/blog/14845424/):

  > At level 10, you’ll unlock the ability to purchase a Hero’s Master
  >   Skin with Gold, which you can use to show off your prowess with that
  >   Hero in-game. Just like other Skins, a Master Skin features two
  >   variations, which you’ll have already unlocked by reaching level 10.
  >   This means that once you’ve purchased a Hero’s Master Skin, you’ll
  >   immediately be able to use its variations in-game.
- and the [Piggy Bank Mount](http://www.heroesfire.com/hots/wiki/mounts/piggy-bank) which is 20,000 gold.

Comment: How much do the elite skins cost? Can you please provide context of what a master skin is?

Comment: I consufed the word master-ksin with elite-skin

Comment: You were right the first time they are Master Skins. :)